# QOpenGLWidget with fixed aspect ratio on a QDock

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I am trying to set up a QOpenGLWidget whose aspect ratio is fixed. The problem is that this widget is inside a QDock so the resizeEvent method disturbs the render i dont know why. How can I do it?

MRE:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QOpenGLWidget, QMainWindow, QApplication, QDockWidget, QLabel


class Renderizador(QOpenGLWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QOpenGLWidget.__init__(self)

        # policy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        # policy.setHeightForWidth(True)
        # self.setSizePolicy(policy)

        # size = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        # size.setHeightForWidth(True)
        # size.setWidthForHeight(True)
        # self.setSizePolicy(size)

    # def heightForWidth(self, width):
    #     return width

    # def sizeHint(self):
    #     return QSize(400, 400)

    # def resizeEvent(self, event):
    #     event.accept()
    #     self.resize(event.size().width(), event.size().height())


class Ventana(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        widget_central = QLabel("Hi")
        widget_central.setGeometry(10, 10, 100, 100)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget_central)
        self.renderizador = Renderizador()
        dock_renderizador = QDockWidget("Render")
        dock_renderizador.setFeatures(QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, dock_renderizador)
        dock_renderizador.setWidget(self.renderizador)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainEvent = QApplication([])
    main_app = Ventana()
    main_app.show()
    MainEvent.exec()
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Done @eyllanesc

Comment: @PepeElMago33 fixed aspect ratio widgets are really difficult to achieve, expecially if they are inserted into a layout; you will probably never be able to be able to adapt the dock widget, but you *could* get a "midway" solution that will almost always have margins on the sides of that widget (horizontal if the available width is higher than what the aspect-ratio would expect, or vertical in the other case).

Comment: @musicamante Are there any other options?

Comment: @PepeElMago33 technically it's not impossible, the problem is that it'd be very, very complex: Qt uses multiple size hint calls of each widget to compute the layout of the central widget, toolbars and dock widgets; things can get messy if multiple dock widgets are allowed in an area, and if tabbing is enabled (with *big* differences between horizontal or vertical tabs) and/or dock nesting is (multiple columns in vertical dock areas, or rows in horizontal areas). Even when providing a dynamic sizeHint that respect your aspect ratio and with a single dock widget, you'll get some problems [>>]

Comment: [>>] and you'll *always* end up with some margin if the contents of the window require more space than left by that dock widget. Imagine a default size of 100x100 for your dock widget in a window that is 400x100 but has widgets that require at least a 300 width, then the user resizes the window to a width of 350x100: Qt will still need those 300 pixel width for the main contents of the window, forcing your dock widget to resize to a 50 pixel width, but still leaving the window height to 100 pixels, so you'll get a 25 + 25 margin on the dock widget anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed aspect ratio for widget is *really* hard to achieve.

While with a "single widget" (a top window) that can be worked around, most times one would like to have fixed aspect ratio for widget that are within a window that has a layout, which possibly contains *other* widgets. With QDockWidgets the situation is even more complex.

There are multiple aspect that has to be taken into account:

- each widget has its own "hints": how it prefers to be show, its minimum or maximum width or height
- the layout of a window (and, possibly, the sub layouts of its child widgets)
- the system might have some contraints (maximum window size, special behavior when the window is near an edge of the screen of another window)
- cross-platform issues seriously limit the possibility of controlling the resizing the "container" top level window

Moreover, in your case more issues come into play; most importantly, a QQMainWindow has [its own private layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework):

[image: QMainWindow layout graph]

Qt internally computes all sizes with an intricate and recursive system of calls to each child widgets, and finally *lays out* all widgets according to their size hints, size policies and widget roles (the "central widget" of a QMainWindows and its contents take precedence over minimum size requirements, but the menuBar and statusBar size hints are also considered).

Also, a QDockWidget can behave differently whether it's floating or not, and if it is it will have to consider *other* existing dock widgets in the selected dock widget area, if the window supports tabbed docks (and if vertical tabs are supported) or nested docks (multiple rows or columns within the same area).

Finally, two important aspects:

- QOpenGLWidget is not *that* fast in resizing itself, which often can result in some flickering when it's dynamically resized.
- As soon as you resize the dockbar using its QSplitter, the hint will be automatically ignored; while this can be *theoretically* addressed too (I don't know how, anyway), it would probably make things even harder.

Long story short: fixed aspect ratio for any widget that is going to be embedded into *any* layout is **always** discouraged.

In the following example I tried to address most of the issues, but keep in mind that this is a very *raw* implementation, has lots of problems (most importantly, the aforementioned flickering: using a standard QWidget descendant the effect is minimized but still present) and, sincerely, I wouldn't suggest its use at all.

As you can see, at first sight it seems that everything's ok:

[image: dock widget looking good]

But, as soon as the dock splitter is moved or the window resized to a width lower than `(dockWidgetMaximumSizeForSquare + minimumWidthOfWidgets)`, the widget gets vertical margins anyway, as there's no horizontal space left.

[image: dock widget looking bad]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Renderizador(QtWidgets.QOpenGLWidget):
    # ...


class RenderizadorContainer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, renderizador=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(20, 20)
        self._currentSize = self.minimumSize()
        self._dirty = False
        self._shown = False
        self._newSize = self.minimumSize()
        self.renderizador = None
        self.setRenderizador(renderizador)

    def setRenderizador(self, renderizador):
        if self.renderizador:
            self.renderizador.setParent(None)
        self.renderizador = renderizador
        if self.renderizador:
            # set the parent to this widget container; this will also "constraint"
            # it to this widget, also limiting its paint area
            self.renderizador.setParent(self)
            self.updateGeometry()

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Resize and event.size().isValid():
            # capture the resize event before it's actually sent to resizeEvent;
            # remember that, at this point, the resize has already happened!
            self._dirty = True
            # the widget has probably not been shown yet, use the minimum size
            # to start with
            self._newSize = event.size() if self._shown else self.minimumSize()
            # notify the layout that the sizeHint has changed
            self.updateGeometry()
        return QtWidgets.QWidget.event(self, event)

    def sizeHint(self):
        if self._dirty:
            self._dirty = False
            # provide the layout a square size hint
            maxSize = max(self._newSize.width(), self._newSize.height())
            self._currentSize = QtCore.QSize(maxSize, maxSize)
            return self._currentSize
        return self._currentSize

    def showEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.showEvent(self, event)
        # the widget is being "mapped", keep track of it
        self._shown = True

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if not self.renderizador:
            return
        # since the "renderizador" is not placed into a layout, its position is
        # "free", and we can set its geometry as we like; let's move it to the
        # center of this widget
        minSize = min(self.width(), self.height())
        rect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, minSize, minSize)
        rect.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
        self.renderizador.setGeometry(rect)


class RenderizadorDockWidget(QtWidgets.QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QDockWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle('Dock test')
        self.newSize = None
        self.topLevelChanged.connect(self.checkNewSize)
        # resizing should *never* happen within a resizeEvent, but in some cases
        # it can be done *after* it; this will minimize flickering, but it will
        # *never* be optimal.
        self.resizeTimer = QtCore.QTimer(
            singleShot=True, interval=0, timeout=self.delayedResize)

    def checkNewSize(self, topLevel):
        if topLevel:
            # whenever the widget is "undocked", it will be resized; since the
            # dock widget has a titlebar, we have to take it into account
            opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionDockWidget()
            self.initStyleOption(opt)
            titleHeight = self.style().subElementRect(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_DockWidgetTitleBarText, opt, self).height()
            minSize = min(self.width(), self.height() - titleHeight)
            self.resize(minSize, minSize)
            if self.widget().renderizador:
                self.widget().renderizador.update()
        elif self.widget().renderizador:
            # the "renderizador" might not be updated instantly after "redocking"
            # the widget; schedule an update to force its repainting
            self.widget().renderizador.update()

    def delayedResize(self):
        if self.newSize is not None and self.isFloating():
            size, delta = self.newSize
            self.newSize = None
            self.resize(size, size + delta)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if self.isFloating() and event.size() != event.oldSize():
            # as for the topLevelChanged, compute the title bar height
            opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionDockWidget()
            self.initStyleOption(opt)
            titleHeight = self.style().subElementRect(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_DockWidgetTitleBarText, opt, self).height()
            newWidth = event.size().width()
            newHeight = event.size().height()
            oldWidth = event.oldSize().width()
            oldHeight = event.oldSize().height()
            if newWidth == oldWidth:
                # width is the same, the reference is the title height
                self.newSize = event.size().height() - titleHeight, titleHeight
            elif newHeight == oldHeight:
                # height is the same, the reference is the width
                self.newSize = event.size().width(), titleHeight
            else:
                # resizing cannot be based on minimum or maximum, while there are
                # various approach for this, I believe that the optimal "hint" is
                # an average value between the difference between width and height
                # of the new size; other single fixed-aspect-ratio-widget based
                # programs use similar methods, like mpv/mplayer
                if not self.newSize:
                    if newWidth != oldWidth:
                        newSize = newWidth - (newWidth - newHeight + titleHeight) / 2
                    else:
                        newSize = newHeight - (newHeight - newWidth) / 2 - titleHeight
                    self.newSize = newSize, titleHeight
                else:
                    oldWidth = self.newSize[0]
                    oldHeight = oldWidth + titleHeight
                    if newWidth != oldWidth:
                        newSize = newWidth - (newWidth - newHeight + titleHeight) // 2
                    else:
                        newSize = newHeight - (newHeight - newWidth) // 2 - titleHeight
                    self.newSize = newSize, titleHeight
            # schedule a resize based on the new size
            self.resizeTimer.start()


class DockTest(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # some random widgets to better show the overall behavior with an existing
        # layout and some minimum size limitations for the window
        central = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Test label'), 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLineEdit(), 0, 1)
        groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(title='Group box')
        layout.addWidget(groupBox, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        groupLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(groupBox)
        groupLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Checkbox'))
        groupLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button'))
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QTableView(), 2, 0, 1, 2)

        self.renderizadorDock = RenderizadorDockWidget()
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.renderizadorDock)
        self.renderizador = Renderizador()
        self.renderizadorDock.setWidget(RenderizadorContainer(self.renderizador))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dockTest = DockTest()
    dockTest.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your answer, musicamante.
I found how to reimplement the resizeEvent for faking the effect:

```py
def resizeEvent(self, event):
    QOpenGLWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)
    if self.width() > self.height():
        self.resize(self.height(), self.height())
    elif self.height() > self.width():
        self.resize(self.width(), self.width())
```

Comment: As I wrote in the comments of my code, resizing should never happen within a resizeEvent. Also, with your code borders are always shown anyway even when the widget could be automatically resized to a square size, which is not what you wanted according to your comments (I told you that there would always be margins and you asked for alternatives). If your solution meets your needs, that's fine, but the next time you'll have to be more clear about what you want.

Comment: Why the resizeEvent shouldnt be used?

Comment: It's not that it shouldn't be used, but using `resize` or `setGeometry` isn't suggested within it as it could lead to infinite recursion (see [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#geometry-prop)). You *could* do it, but you'll need to be very careful and remember that each resizing also results in widget repainting. If you're ok with the margins and don't care about the dock aspect ratio when floating, I'd suggest you to use a QWidget as "container" for a child gl widget (no layout) and just implement the resizeEvent to set the child geometry, as the RenderizadorContainer in my example.